# How resolved AsciiDoc Error java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.List

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, asciidoctor

That code take me an error, i try with Spring Boot and Mockito, Junit4:

```
@PostMapping(value = Constants.LOGOUT_URL)
public String logout (HttpServletRequest request) throws ApiException {

    String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (authHeader != null) {
        try {
            String tokenValue = authHeader.replace("Bearer", "").trim();
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
            tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString();
        }
    }
    return Utils.convertDateTime();
}


@Test
public void logout() throws Exception, ApiException {

    //String result = "{\"date\":\"20190212:0000\"}";
    //Mockito.when(controller.logout(any())).thenReturn(result);

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(REST_REQUEST_PATH)
            .header("principal", "admin")
            .header("authorization", "authtoken")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept("application/json"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(document("logout",
                    responseFields(fieldWithPath("date").description("Fecha de entrega de la respuesta.")
                    )));
}
```

This is the Stack Trace error

```
14:17:29.972 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name '': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
```

14:17:29.973 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.List

```
at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.JsonContentHandler.isEmpty(JsonContentHandler.java:147)
at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.JsonContentHandler.getUndocumentedContent(JsonContentHandler.java:119)
at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.AbstractFieldsSnippet.validateFieldDocumentation(AbstractFieldsSnippet.java:242)
at org.springframework.restdocs.payload.AbstractFieldsSnippet.createModel(AbstractFieldsSnippet.java:169)
at org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.TemplatedSnippet.document(TemplatedSnippet.java:83)
at org.springframework.restdocs.generate.RestDocumentationGenerator.handle(RestDocumentationGenerator.java:206)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationResultHandler.handle(RestDocumentationResultHandler.java:55)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andDo(MockMvc.java:183)
at com.sodexo.oneapp.api.auth.AuthControllerTest.logout(AuthControllerTest.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.restdocs.JUnitRestDocumentation$1.evaluate(JUnitRestDocumentation.java:63)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: There is no question.

Comment: When i put the asciidoc code take me a java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.List  error

Comment: Can you add the stack trace you are seeing when this fails?

Comment: put the stack trace error together code

Comment: It looks like the response you are trying to document with Spring REST Docs is a single number. REST Docs expects either a JSON object or a JSON array.